Exporting an object with modifiers
I have an animation of an anchor dropping that I want to export to unity, but 2 of the objects have modifiers on them which unity does not support. I created the animation by applying an array and curve modifier to a singular chain link to form a full chain, and moved the vertices of a curve using shapekeys so that the chain would deform to follow the anchor as it falls.
I can apply the modifiers at any frame in the animation to get the geometry of the chain, but it will no longer follow the curve anymore without the array and curve modifiers. Is there a way to splice together the geometry obtained from each frame to get the animation I want? I've heard of people using animation baking for physics simulations and stuff so that the end result is stored without running the simulation multiple times, but I don't know if this is right for my project.
The geometry of the mesh also changes by having certain links deleted and added, because my array modifier is set to "fit curve," so it isn't just deforming the mesh. Is it possible to keep this animation, or do I need to animate it a different way to make it function in unity?

What file format are you using to export to Unity? FBX, glTF?

This question is similar to: How can I do a cartoon-like cannon firing animation that's compatible with Unity (without lattice modifier)?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Phrogz, ideally FBX, but any file format that allows me to accomplish my goal is good

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

@Emir, the concept the post is related to is pretty much the same, but I don't think it can work for my animation specifically. Whenever I try to export my model as a .mdd in step 3 of the solution of the post you linked, it throws an error. I think its due to the deletion of some of the chain links during the the animation, because it says that "the number of verts has changed during this animation."

I didn't exactly fix the issue, but i made an armature and put bones on each chain link, then used automatic IK to get a similar new animation without having modifiers.
